# Unable to invite my friends to like my friend's business page

Tags: facebook-like

I am unable to invite my friends to like a friend's business page. When I click into the business page, there is no option to invite my friends to like the page. I am definitely on my personal page when I try to do this.

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The option to invite friends should be on the left on the page under the subsection "People"

[image: Invite your friends to like this Page]